# Android Game GC Lag? How to fix It?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have created [a small game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.game.squirrelrun&hl=en) and when I play it, I am experiencing very large lag spikes at certain intervals; When I look at the logcat output, I can see that the lag is caused by the garbage collector. Now I have adjusted my code to adhere with all the rules in regards to how to formulate for loops to not create garbage, and I have created all of the objects before the game starts. However, the lag is still present.

I look at games like Flappy Bird, and it has no lag whatsoever despite its simplicity. What am I doing wrong?

I'll post code if need be.

Here is the Collision code:

```
branchesSize = Level.branches.size();
    for (int x = 0; x < branchesSize; ++x) {
        if (yPos <= Level.branches.get(x).yPos
                + Level.branches.get(x).height
                && yPos >= Level.branches.get(x).yPos) {
            if (xPos <= Level.branches.get(x).xPos
                    + Level.branches.get(x).width
                    && xPos >= Level.branches.get(x).xPos) {
                // DEATH
                death();
            }
        }

        if (yPos + height / 2 >= Level.branches.get(x).yPos
                && yPos + height / 2 <= Level.branches.get(x).yPos
                        + Level.branches.get(x).height) {
            if (xPos + width <= Level.branches.get(x).xPos
                    + Level.branches.get(x).width
                    && xPos + width >= Level.branches.get(x).xPos) {
                // DEATH
                death();
            }
        }

        if (yPos >= Level.branches.get(x).yPos
                && yPos <= Level.branches.get(x).yPos
                        + Level.branches.get(x).height) {
            if (xPos + width <= Level.branches.get(x).xPos
                    + Level.branches.get(x).width
                    && xPos + width >= Level.branches.get(x).xPos) {
                // DEATH
                death();
            }
        }

        // Collect Nuts
        nutsSize = Level.nuts.size();
        for (int y = 0; y < nutsSize; ++y) {
            if (yPos <= Level.nuts.get(y).yPos) {
                nuts += 1;
                Level.nuts_available.add(Level.nuts.get(0));
                Level.nuts.remove(0);
                nutsSize -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell. GC cleaning up much means your allocating too much memory...Check you sources for "new" statements, see if you can reuse some objects, ...

Comment: also look at the size of the images you are loading...

Comment: The images are very small: 56 x 72 etc. And i only have new statements at the start of the application, not during .

Comment: Wild guess, maybe you did your own physics/collision and create there loads of vectors/matrices?

Comment: I created int x and int y to check for collision. Is that wrong? I added Collision Code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a heap dump of your program and analyze it using MAT or JHAT and see what is your memory filled with when there is a lot of memory usage,